# How to get a certain part from an HttpGET request query string

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api2, http-get

I need to get a certain part from a GET request query string. For example, if the query string is:

```
action=balance&id=123&session_id=123&key=3843
```

I would like to convert it to

```
action=balance&id=123&session_id=123
```

i.e. I would like to cut off the `key` parameter part. How could I do that?

Comment: why don't you use string.split()

Comment: Please specify language of choice. I have written sample for javascript.

Comment: in asp.net you can use split function which will return array and you can  rearrange them leaving last one

Answer (score 0):

After a short googling, I've found the answer here: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/574956/How-to-get-URL-and-QueryString-value-in-an-ASP-NET

In short, you are able to retrieve what you are looking for by using the following method:

```
Request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING")
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Why do you show how to get the query string although the OP already has the query string? Well, his wording is a bit unclear, but if you read the question thoroughly, you see that he already has the query string, and his question is how to get a certain part of that string.

Answer (score 0):

use the substring function in your language of choice

for eg. in javascript you can do it as

```
 var f = "action=balance&id=123&session_id=123&key=3843";

 var a = f.replace(f.substring(f.indexOf('&key')),"");
```

There are lot of other ways also.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Regex.Replace(Request.RawUrl, @"&key.*", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

string qs = Request.params;

This will return collection of all params in curre

Comment: That answer won't help the OP. As qs is a string, he has exactly the same problem as before.

Comment: do you have any alternate solution for that @Binarus

Comment: Some solutions are mentioned in the other comments or answers. But watch out for the pitfalls ...

Answer (score 0):

Get the Last Index Of char '&'. Then get the substring.

```
string url = Request.params; 

int index = url.LastIndexOf('&');

var urlWithOutKey = url.Substring(0, index);
```

Comment: This solution works in this special case, but does not work if the `&key` parameter is not the last one. After all, you can't predict in which order the parameters (generated by browser, client-side code, shell scripts etc.) are found in the query string.

Answer (score 0):

I have investigated a little bit more and find out this solution

```
        string url = Request.RequestUri.ToString();
        Uri uri = new Uri(url);
        string urlStringQuery = uri.Query;
        int endIndex = urlStringQuery.IndexOf("&key", 1);
        string query = urlStringQuery.Substring(1, endIndex - 1);
```

Comment: This will fail if there is another parameter like `&keyword`. Furthermore, you can't rely on the order of parameters in a query string. If the `&key` parameter is not the last one, this will fail as well.

Comment: There is sense in your words,but i am writing this API according some documentation which already have described URL format with exact parameters consequence